# NetFilterHook: Displaly Interface Name

Tags: linux-kernel, hook, kernel-module, netfilter

How can filter and/or display the name of the interface the packet has arrived from in the **Kernel space**?

More specifcally I want the name of the interfacen e.g eth0, wlan1 etc to be printed out in the kernel.

Secondly how can I filter packets only from a specific interface e.g eth0 only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the hook function, there is parameters `const struct net_device *in` and `const struct net_device *out`.
You can print it by:

```
printk(KERN_INFO "%s\n", out->name);
```

or:

```
printk(KERN_INFO "%s\n", in->name);
```

Note: You need to check if is null.

About the second question, you can use in the hook function in `strcmp(in->name, "eth0")`, and then decide drop or accept.

Comment: The commnand `printk(KERN_INFO "%s\n", in->name);` is just printing a blank space?

Comment: And If is change it to `printk(KERN_INFO "%s\n", out->name);` the kernel panics and my laptop hangs

Comment: Both should print the name of the device. If the hook function registered on the incoming packets, you should use `printk(KERN_INFO "%s\n", in->name);`. the output is "eth0", "eth1" etc.

Comment: If you need more help, please let me know what exactly are you trying to do.

Comment: Thank You very much the problem it seems was with my laptop. The above is working fine in another computer